# Javascript slowly "flush" DOM Tree

Tags: javascript

I have really strange problem. I'm trying to get width and height of an image using following way:

1. Create a image tag and add .src to it.
2. add this image tag to document.body.
3. making this image tag visible (display:inline).
4. getting .offsetWidth and .offsetHeight of element.
5. hidding image tag(display:none);

all this is done using JS and it all work really well on my localhost, but when I uploaded a site to my client hosting provider I was amazed. offsetWidth and .offsetHeight was 0 in step 4. Why do that happen? I think that I need some kind of "flush" after step 3 before step 4, but I'm not exactly sure. Any suggestions ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wait for the image to actually load over the network.  You don't need to add the thing to the DOM either:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
  handleImageSize(this.width, this.height);
};
img.src = "http://whatever.com/your/img.jpg";
```

Here, "handleImageSize" would be a function you write to do whatever it is you need to do with the image dimensions.

Comment: this solution doesn't work in IE or I have tested some wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This was probably caused by the image not being loaded yet. Try something like this:

```
img.onload = function() {
  // get the offsetWidth and offsetHeight
}
```

Comment: I'm doing everything using onclick event so everything is loaded, but maybe really image isn't still downloaded by browser....

Answer (score 0):

As other answers suggest, is due to the image not being fully loaded by the DOM. This was working fine on your local server as I suspect you were loading images locally, meaning they were almost instantaneous; however after moving them to the server there is a slight delay. It's an easily overlooked problem, that is easily fixed.

Other answers will do the trick; but here's the jQuery version for sake of argument

```
var img = $('<img>', {
    src: 'http://dummyimage.com/150/000/fff.gif'
}).one('load', function() {
    var offsets = $(this).offset();
});

$('body').append(img);
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rGnBw/)

Comment: `one` is intentional; unless the image `src` is changing, it will only load once. :)

Comment: Ahh, apologies. Learn something new every day!

Comment: I catch your idea and I will try it.